# PHP PDO code connecting to database but not executing queries and not returning errors

Tags: php, oop, pdo

I am trying to create a user registration and login system. My code is connecting to the database and form is feeding data but the statements does not execute. There are no error messages either.

```
public function reg_user($username, $email, $address, $pwd){
    $pass = password_hash($pwd, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
    $check = $this->db->prepare('SELECT * FROM bakery_users WHERE u_mail = :u_mail');
    $check->bindParam(':u_mail', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $check->execute();
    $count = $check->rowCount();

    if($count < 0){
        $reg = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO bakery_users (u_name, u_mail, u_add u_pass) VALUES (:u_name, :u_mail, :u_add, :u_pass)');
        $reg->bindParam(':u_mail', $username,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $reg->bindParam(':u_mail', $email,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $reg->bindParam(':u_add', $address,PDO::PARAM_STR); 
        $reg->bindParam(':u_pass', $pass,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $reg->execute();
        return true;
    }else{
        $db = null;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Most probably count returns 0 or larger than 0... not less than 0

Comment: You are missing a comma in your insert statement. Between `u_add` and `u_pass`.

Comment: How are you expecting `$count` to be **less** than zero?

Comment: If you mod your question every time someone gives you an answer, it makes the answers look wrong !!! So please dont do that. If you want to say you have changed things and it still does not work then re-paste the amended code under a UPDATE title if you must.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem, I believe, lies in the sql statement - it is missing a comma between `u_add` and `u_pass`

```
$reg = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO bakery_users (u_name, u_mail, u_add, u_pass) VALUES (:u_name, :u_mail, :u_add, :u_pass)');
```

If you test the return value of `prepare` you can fork the logic dependant upon it's success/failure

```
        if( $reg ){
            $reg->bindParam(':u_mail', $username,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $reg->bindParam(':u_mail', $email,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $reg->bindParam(':u_add', $address,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $reg->bindParam(':u_pass', $pass,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $reg->execute();
            return true;            
        } else {
            exit('error');
        }
```

You also have a misnamed parameter in the first bind statement

```
$reg->bindParam(':u_mail', $username,PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

should be

```
$reg->bindParam(':u_name', $username,PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

You can use a `try/catch` block to try to identify problems in a constructive manner like this

```
public function reg_user($username, $email, $address, $pwd){
    try{
        $pass = password_hash($pwd, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
        $check = $this->db->prepare('SELECT * FROM `bakery_users` WHERE `u_mail` = :u_mail');
        if( !$check )throw new Exception('Failed to prepare SELECT query');

        $check->bindParam(':u_mail', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $check->execute();
        $count = $check->rowCount();

        if( $count < 0 ){

            $reg = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO `bakery_users` (`u_name`, `u_mail`, `u_add`, `u_pass` ) VALUES ( :u_name, :u_mail, :u_add, :u_pass )');

            if( $reg ){
                $reg->bindParam(':u_name', $username,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $reg->bindParam(':u_mail', $email,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $reg->bindParam(':u_add', $address,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $reg->bindParam(':u_pass', $pass,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $reg->execute();

                return true;            
            } else {
                throw new Exception('Failed to prepare INSERT query')
            }
        } else{
           $db = null;
           return false;
        }
    }catch( Exception $e ){
        exit( sprintf('An error "%s" on line %d of "%s"',$e->getMessage(),$e->getLine(),__METHOD__ ) );
    }
}
```

I should have spotted sooner the use of `if( $count < 0 )` ~ that should be `if( $count==0 )`

```
public function reg_user( $username=false, $email=false, $address=false, $pwd=false ){
    try{
        if( !( $username & $email & $address & $pwd ) ) throw new Exception('bad foo');

        $sql='SELECT * FROM `bakery_users` WHERE `u_mail` = :u_mail';
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare( $sql );

        if( !$stmt ) throw new Exception('Failed to prepare SELECT query');

        $args=array( ':u_mail' => $email );
        $stmt->execute( $args );
        $count = $stmt->rowCount();

        if( $count == 0 ){
            $sql='INSERT INTO `bakery_users` ( `u_name`, `u_mail`, `u_add`, `u_pass` ) VALUES ( :u_name, :u_mail, :u_add, :u_pass )';
            $stmt = $db->prepare( $sql );
            if( $stmt ){
                $args=array(
                    ':u_name'   =>  $username,
                    ':u_mail'   =>  $email,
                    ':u_add'    =>  $address,
                    ':u_pass'   =>  password_hash( $pwd, PASSWORD_BCRYPT )
                );
                return $stmt->execute( $args );       
            } else {
                throw new Exception('Failed to prepare INSERT query')
            }
        } else{
           $db = null;
           return false;
        }
    }catch( Exception $e ){
        exit( sprintf( 'An error "%s" on line %d of "%s"', $e->getMessage(), $e->getLine(), __METHOD__ ) );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> There are no error messages either

because you're using the wrong PDO error mode, you're using the default one, which, iirc, is called `PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT`

this is *THE* correct way to create a PDO object:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=utf8mb4', 'username', 'password', 
array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
```

and when you created yours, you forgot the `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`-part.

Comment: Thanks @hanshenrik! But still no errors. here is the full connection code                                                `class BakeryModel {
      public $db;
      function __construct(){
          
            
     try{
     $this->db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=bakerydb;charset=utf8mb4', 'root', '', 
array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));


     } 
      catch (PDOEXCEPTION $e){
         echo "connection failed:" .$e->getMessage();
       }
        
   }
`.

Comment: @Zeekstem oh, then it's probably a PHP `White screen of death`, you have an uncaught exception, and you have `display_errors = Off` in php.ini, the error log should be waiting for you at the php error log :) (ps, in most configurations, the php error log is redirected to the webserver's error log, so most often it's apache's error log or nginx's error log)